# Why is my receipt not printing on my shop?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have created a shop and it should print a receipt for the customer but when I go to print it says no pages found.

It should be working after I click the print button to print the page and show preview but its saying nothing to show.

Why is it not printing?

```c#
int shopitemid, shopquantity, shopprice, shoptotal, pos = 60;
        string shopname;
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("The Androids Dungeon", new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, new Point(80));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("ID Product Price Quantity Total", new Font("Century Gothic", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, new Point(26,40));
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datafrmcheckout.Rows)
            {
                shopitemid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column1"].Value);
                shopname = "" + row.Cells["Column2"].Value;
                shopprice = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column3"].Value);
                shopquantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column4"].Value);
                shoptotal = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column5"].Value);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("" + shopitemid, new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(26, pos));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("" + shopname, new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(45, pos));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("" + shopprice, new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(120, pos));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("" + shopquantity, new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(170, pos));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("" + shoptotal, new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(235, pos));
                pos = pos + 20;

            }
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total: £ " +grdtotal , new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Crimson, new Point(60, pos + 50));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("***The Android Dungeon***", new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Crimson, new Point(40, pos + 85));
            datafrmcheckout.Rows.Clear();
            datafrmcheckout.Refresh();
            pos = 100;
            grdtotal = 0;

        }

        private void Printbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("pprnm", 285, 600);
           if(printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a debugging issue.  What is happening when you step through the code line by line?

Comment: When I debug I get no issues!

Comment: If it prints fine the first time, then maybe it's because you are clearing out the data grid at the end of your printing?

Comment: It didnt print fine the first time either its always said no page to print

Comment: OK, we're back to what happens when you debug it.  Are you saying it works when you debug it?

Comment: sorry my bad, When i debug it it runs and nothing happens no errors are found! but there is no page to print. so obviously thats not right

Comment: That's not how debugging works.  Put a debug stop on the first line :`e.Graphics.DrawString...` then run your program and try to do the print.  When the program stops on the line, press F11 to see what happens on every line.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but i cant get it working is there any chance you could hop an a quick 2 min call and try help me I would really appreciate it

Comment: No, that's not how stackoverflow works.  Do you have the PrintPage event subscribed?  Sounds like it's not.  In your form's constructor: `printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;`